# Rails and locales for a beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

I'm trying to understand how to set locales.

Right now, my application controller has:

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = user_signed_in? ? current_user.local.to_sym : :en
end
```

This works well, but if I want to add a quick switch button on the log in page (which won't have session info because there's no `current_user`...how can I do this?

Comment: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have a `current_user` to have a session. Every request that hits your app will have a `session` object available to it where you can persist data.

Your `set_locale` can use the locale stored in `session`as the default (falling back to `:en`) if the user isn't currently logged in:

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = user_signed_in? ? current_user.local.to_sym : (session[:locale] || :en)
end
```

You just need a method which sets the locale based on the user's submitted locale.

Comment: Cool! If I want a button that says "switch locale" to change that...how does that work via routes or session var??

Answer (score 0):

You can make a chain that figures out the current locale from many sources with priorities. The sources are (in order):

1. The current `GET` variable `lang`. I like to use it when a user wants to see only the current page in another locale. It neither changes his preference locale nor session locale.
2. The `lang` variable in the `session` which is applied to a whole session. So a user might like to browse multiple pages in the website in a locale different from his preference one, but without having to set the GET `lang` variable on every request and without having to change the locale in his preferences, and this is where `session` comes in. It applies only to the current... session :)
3. The locale in his preferences.
4. The default locale of the application (`I18n.defaul_locale`) which defaults to `:en` if you don't set it manually.

My code looks like:

```
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale
    if user_signed_in?
        I18n.locale = params[:lang] || session[:lang] || current_user.locale || I18n.default_locale
    else
        I18n.locale = params[:lang] || session[:lang] || I18n.default_locale
    end
end
```

Comment: This looks good. If I want to set a session[:lang] for a user not logged in, how would I set that??

Comment: @KevinBrown simply `session[:lang] = :en` should work.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do that between front/backend.

Comment: @KevinBrown I think you should've explained more. Is a multilingual sign in page all what you want, or you want to allow anonymous visitors to choose a language, or there's another problem?

Comment: I'd like anonymous users to choose a language...not sure how to set the lang session from the front-end is all...I've got it all working fine after I have a user logged in.